# Trimming PS Objects As Though They Are Strings

Tags: powershell

I have an array, `$final`, where each element in the array is a custom object. Each object is a computername in the form 'computername@ipaddress' (ex: AJFFF01@10.10.10.10). What I need is a list of the computer names without the '@IPADRESS'. I've tried using `.toString()` on each item, however it returns nothing. Please help!

Below is the output of Get-member of `$final` (which provides the same methods for `$final[0] | gm`):

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $final | gm


   TypeName: Selected.System.Xml.XmlElement

Name        MemberType   Definition                                
----        ----------   ----------                                
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)            
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                         
GetType     Method       type GetType()                            
ToString    Method       string ToString()                         
#text       NoteProperty System.String #text=AJFFF09@10.10.10.10
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

so it looks like you have an array of XmlElements rather than an array of custom objects.  Further it appears that there is a #text property available that contains the string you are looking for.  You'd be able to access that by calling `$final[0].'#text'` (make sure to remember the quotes around the property name).  Then you'd have to parse the string to remove the extra data but you can do that either using regex matches or .substring() methods.

Answer (score 0):

An simple way to get the required data is to use `split`

Refer to the below for better understanding:

```
$Array='AJFFF01@10.10.10.10'
$CompName=$array.split('@')[0]
$CompName
```

Hope it HElps.